# What is the best way to migrate my OS and programs to an SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a new ssd and I currently have in my computer an hdd with the operating system..and all. The classic windows intallation in "C:\".
I only want in my ssd the operating system and the programs, not the data. I was wondering how should I do the migration.
I could just install the OS again with the programs, but that's a bit of a nonsense. What is the best option to migrate ONLY to the ssd with the OS and the software that I actually have? I was thinking about that maybe with a system image this would be fine and done, but, with the system image am I going to get the data too?
I have to say that I have literally all in one partition.
So what do you think is the best way to do this so I don't waste space on my ssd with data that I could have in my hdd?

Comment: Possible duplicate; https://superuser.com/questions/1017359/how-can-i-migrate-my-windows-10-os-from-an-hdd-to-an-ssd?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I migrate my Windows 10 OS from an HDD to an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1017359/how-can-i-migrate-my-windows-10-os-from-an-hdd-to-an-ssd)